# How does the workflow query both the individual tasks and the candidate group tasks?

Tags: java, activiti

I have connected them using or and endOr,but now only the candidate group tasks can be queried.Can you give me some help?

```
TaskQuery taskQuery = taskService.createTaskQuery().active().**or()**;
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userId)) {
        taskQuery.taskAssignee(userId);
}
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty((String) params.get("taskName"))) {
        taskQuery.taskNameLike("%" + (String) params.get("taskName") + "%");
}

Long listRoles = sysRoleUserService.getRoleIdList(SecurityUser.getUserId());
List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<>();
listStr.add(listRoles.toString());
listStr.add(SecurityUser.getUserId().toString());
if (!listStr.isEmpty()) {
        taskQuery.taskCandidateGroupIn(listStr);
}
taskQuery.**endOr()**.orderByTaskCreateTime().desc();
List<Task> list = taskQuery.listPage((curPage - 1) * limit, limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I built two queries and merged them manually.